# Unable to deploy with rails and capistrano, "HEAD is not the same as origin/master"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, capistrano

I keep getting an error when trying to deploy with capistrano to my remote server. It is telling me that my local files aren't synced up to the remote repo, but when I `git push` I get  the `Everything is up-to-date` message. I'm not sure what the problem is. I've also checked the rev-parse for both origin and HEAD and they return the same values.

Error:

```
WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master
Run `git push` to sync changes.
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host [IP address]
exit

SystemExit: exit

Tasks: TOP => deploy:starting => deploy:check_revision
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing on host [IP address]: exit
```

deploy.rb

```
# Change these
server '[ipaddress]', port: 22, roles: [:web, :app, :db], primary: true

set :repo_url,        'git@github.com:name/rails_site.git'
set :application,     'rails_site'
set :user,            'deploy'
set :puma_threads,    [4, 16]
set :puma_workers,    0

# Don't change these unless you know what you're doing
set :pty,             true
set :use_sudo,        false
set :stage,           :production
set :deploy_via,      :remote_cache
set :deploy_to,       "/home/#{fetch(:user)}/apps/#{fetch(:application)}"
set :puma_bind,       "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/#{fetch(:application)}-puma.sock"
set :puma_state,      "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid,        "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_access_log, "#{release_path}/log/puma.error.log"
set :puma_error_log,  "#{release_path}/log/puma.access.log"
set :ssh_options,     { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) }
set :puma_preload_app, true
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, true  # Change to false when not using ActiveRecord

## Defaults:
 set :scm,           :git
 set :branch,        :master
 set :format,        :pretty
 set :log_level,     :debug
 set :keep_releases, 5

## Linked Files & Directories (Default None):
# set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
# set :linked_dirs,  %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

namespace :puma do
  desc 'Create Directories for Puma Pids and Socket'
  task :make_dirs do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/sockets -p"
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/pids -p"
    end
  end

  before :start, :make_dirs
end

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision do
    on roles(:app) do
      unless 'git rev-parse HEAD' === 'git rev-parse origin/master'
        puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
        puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
        exit
      end
    end
  end

  desc 'Initial Deploy'
  task :initial do
    on roles(:app) do
      before 'deploy:restart', 'puma:start'
      invoke 'deploy'
    end
  end

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      invoke 'puma:restart'
    end
  end

  before :starting,     :check_revision
  after  :finishing,    :compile_assets
  after  :finishing,    :cleanup
  after  :finishing,    :restart
end

# ps aux | grep puma    # Get puma pid
# kill -s SIGUSR2 pid   # Restart puma
# kill -s SIGTERM pid   # Stop puma
```

EDIT:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean

$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why you wrote this:

```
unless 'git rev-parse HEAD' === 'git rev-parse origin/master'
```

instead of this:

```
unless `git rev-parse HEAD` === `git rev-parse origin/master`
```

If it is a typo, I'll remove this answer. If not, you are comparing string instead of result of commands.

also you can use:

```
unless %x{git rev-parse HEAD} === %x{git rev-parse origin/master}
```

see more at [method ` definition](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-60). Also I prefer use == instead of === (but for strings is the same).

Comment: Also if you want to deploy from a different branch, say `develop`, you can set the branch name with ```set :branch :develop``` and then compare with branch `develop` instead of `master`: ```unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/#{fetch(:branch)}` ```

Comment: Use this code in deploy.rb file
-----
**unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/<your_branch_name`
      puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
      puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
      exit
end**
-----

Answer (score 1):

In your `deploy.rb`, comment temporary the `before :starting, :check_revision` and deploy without committing this change.

Comment: while this may answer thew question, it is better to include essential parts on how this will solve the issue and also try to identify where the user is going wrong and why

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I have a solution for you.  I have tested it on my machine and it works.  Please be advised that this feels like a hack and might not be the most efficient answer.  Nevertheless, it works.

Follow these steps to remove your existing project, clone a new one, and merge what you have locally with what you have in git:

```
# back out of your project
cd ..

# delete your project
sudo rm -r yourproject

# clone fresh instance of your project
git clone https://github.com/yourusername/yourproject.git

# navigate to your project
cd yourproject

# remove .git folder
sudo rm -r .git

# initialize a new .git
git init

# add all files for upcoming commit/merge
git add .

# set commit
git commit -m "refreshed sync"

# set remote origin to merge with
git remote add origin https://github.com/yourusername/yourproject.git

# make a pull to merge the two
# you will enter a nano screen to enter comment
# press CTRL + X to continue
git pull https://github.com/yourusername/yourproject.git

# push to remote location and set upstream
git push --set-upstream origin master

# Now you're all set!
```

Comment: We have two options here, either clone what you have in git to a fresh directory or try to set what you have locally as the upstream.  Before I suggest anything further, can you please post the output of the following while in your project's directory? `git status` and `git branch -a`

Comment: git status: `$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean` git branch -a: `$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master`

Comment: I cloned a fresh directory and tried it, and it's still giving me the same error

Comment: @LiamHarwood please see updated answer.  That should work for you.

Comment: Sadly, that didn't fix the problem either. Maybe it's a problem with capistrano or my deploy.rb rather than a problem with git??

Comment: hmmm... once you pushed everything to git and set the upstream what happened?  Same error message?  If there was anything different, please update your question to include.

Answer (score 0):

Use `git branch` to check if you are in different branch. If your server use master branch, then `git checkout master` `git push` solved my issue.